# Why Tizen studio clear the local storage every time while running the tizen tv web app?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I'm developing a Samsung Smart TV wepApp using Tizen Studio. Where I'm using local web storage to store some data. So when I runs the app (Right click on project > Debug as > Tizen Web Application) for debugging, they clear the local store of old build.

I expect the run the app without cleaning the local storage of app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the way that Tizen works. Every time you run or debug the app Tizen uninstall and then install the app.

Due privacy policies Tizen clears the app data on the uninstall process so every try is like the first time

Best regards

Comment: Local storage is being removed in real tv device. I am debugging with real tv device, and once app installed on tv device, i am restarting tv device, but everytime app is starting in tv device, local storage is being cleared automatically, I can't read previously saved settings.

Comment: You should be able to use the HTML localStorage to save all app preferences. In order to discard any other issues please check you don't have enabled the Hotel Mode in the TV (due privacy policy in hotel model the TV restore lot of data to previous state)

Comment: I didn't enable hotel mode in tizen studio and tv device.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your project **->** `Run As` **->** `Run Configurations...`

Select the appropriate run configuration (e.g. Tizen Web Application) you are using and tick on **Enable update mode**. Then `Apply` **->** `Run`

From next time, Right Click on your project **->** `Run As`/`Debug As` **->** `Tizen Web Application`